# Issue in Exporting SSRS Reports to CSV

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services

I have an SSRS Report in which few columns will be made visible programmatically. The Report gets generated succesfully, but when it's exported to CSV, the columns whose "visible" attribute has been handled programmatically doesn't get exproted to CSV.

1. Is there a work-around for this
   issue?
2. What is the best way to implement
       hide logic for columns in SSRS so
       that there are no issues while
       exproting to CSV/Excel?

Comment: Hmmm, are you setting the visible property at the column, or at the cell, level?

Comment: visible property has been set at column level

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bimusings/archive/2007/02/07/reporting-services-why-aren-t-all-my-report-columns-exporting-to-csv-and-or-xml.aspx which explains that CSV (and XML) is a data format rather than a layout format. If the visibility is toggled via a formula as you're doing, it won't be rendered at all in CSV (even if the visibility setting makes it visible).